# Using PHP array iterator to edit array

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I have a multidimensional array with variable number of levels of data. That is, I can't be sure how many iterations it will take to reach the `Goal` level, which is an array. Something like this:

```
[ 
    'key1' = 'value1',
    'key2' = 'value2',
    'key3' = [
        'key4' => [
            'key5' => 'value3'
            ],
        'key6' => 'value4'
    ],
    'key7' => [
        'Goal' => [
            'value5',
            'value6',
            'value7'
        ]
    ],
    'key8' => 'value8'],
    'key9' => [
        'Goal' => [
            'value9',
            'Foo',
            'value10'
        ]
    ]
]
```

I've tried both `array_walk_recursive` and `ArrayIterator`, but neither seems to quite get me where I need to be.

I need to go through each element of the array, and if the key is `Goal` examine the value (eg. the array that `Goal` holds) and see if that array contains the value `Foo`.

If `Foo` is found in the array, I need to add a new value (in addition to `Foo`-- so call it `Bar`) to the array and then continue, since there may be more `Goals` in the parent array.

Is there a way to "stop" the iterator when we find a `Goal`, without iterating further, and then do the `array_search` operation?

Edit: Trying somethings along these lines--

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)); 
foreach($iterator as $key => $value)
{
   if($key == 'Goal')
   {
       if (is_array($value)) {
           if(array_search('Foo', $value)) {
               $value[] = 'Bar';
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: SHow the code you currently have, it will at least clear up what you are trying to do

Comment: Something like this? https://eval.in/427733

Comment: @RobbieAverill-- that's very nearly what is needed, but for two things-- 1) there can be multiple `Goals` in the array, and 2) I need the whole array returned, with the `Bar` additions, rather than just the `Goal` node. Thanks, you've gotten me much closer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you want to achieve but here's a solution which adds `Bar` to arrays nested in the `Goal` key:

```php
$array = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => [
        'key4' => [
            'key5' => 'value3',
        ],
        'key6' => 'value4',
    ],
    'key7' => [
        'Goal' => [
            'value5',
            'value6',
            'value7',
        ],
    ],
    'key8' => 'value8',
    'key9' => [
        'Goal' => [
            'value9',
            'Foo',
            'value10',
        ],
    ],
];

function iterate(array $data, $goal = false)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = iterate($value, $key === 'Goal');

        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            if (($value === 'Foo') && $goal) {
                $data[] = 'Bar';
                return $data;
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

var_export(iterate($array));
```

The code generates the following output:

```
array (
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2',
  'key3' => 
  array (
    'key4' => 
    array (
      'key5' => 'value3',
    ),
    'key6' => 'value4',
  ),
  'key7' => 
  array (
    'Goal' => 
    array (
      0 => 'value5',
      1 => 'value6',
      2 => 'value7',
    ),
  ),
  'key8' => 'value8',
  'key9' => 
  array (
    'Goal' => 
    array (
      0 => 'value9',
      1 => 'Foo',
      2 => 'value10',
      3 => 'Bar',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterators in my opinion would be weird to use in these kind of arrays... I would do it with something like this:

```
/*
    Usage:
            $wasFound = checkArray( "Goal", "Foo", $the_array);
            if ( $wasFound ) echo "Key and Value pair found in the array!";
            else { /* not found */ }
*/

function checkArray( $key_to_find, $value_to_find, $my_var, $last_key = NULL ) {
    $found = FALSE;

    if ( $last_key == $key_to_find && $my_var == $value_to_find )
        return TRUE;

    if ( $my_var == NULL )
        return FALSE;

    if ( is_array( $my_var ) ) {
        foreach ( $my_var AS $key => $value )
        {
            if ( $found ) {
                /* Do something else if needed when found */
                break;
            }

            $found = checkArray( $key_to_find, $value_to_find, $value, $key );
        }
    }

    return $found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that recursion is the way to do this. The problem with using `array_walk_recursive` is that you will not be able to see the `Goal` key, because as per the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php),

> Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function.

I am not really sure whether using a `RecursiveIteratorIterator` would be better than just writing a recursive function for it. A function for something like this should be fairly simple.

```
function addBar(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if ($key === 'Goal') {
            if(array_search('Foo', $value)) {
                $value[] = 'Bar';
            }
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            addBar($value);
        }
    }
}
```

This function takes a reference to your array, so it will update your actual array rather than creating a copy with `Bar` added to each `Goal`.